# Re-rendering react component when state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to use react Hooks to update my react component when a change to the state holding the api information occurs. I'm currently creating a quiz application where the user can create a quiz , by entering data such as title and answers, which is then sent to a mongodb. When the user is not editing the quiz, I want to display the updated values from the database .
For example:

parent component

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export default function Context() {
   const [data,setData] = useState(null);
   const [selected,setSelected] = useState(id); // id is taken from url
   useEffect(() => {
      getKahootQuestion();
  }, [data])

    async function getKahootQuestion(slide) {
    if(selected !== undefined) {
        let getKahootQuestion = await withData(`quizQuestion/single/${selected}`,'GET');
        if(getKahootQuestion) {
            setData(getKahootQuestion.data);
            console.log(getKahootQuestion);
        }
    }
  }


}


export default function MainContent() {
   // I want to be able to add items to Database and re-render components to reflect the changes
  let context = useContext(Context);
  let title = context.data[0].title;

     async function submitTitle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let form = e.currentTarget;
        let title = form['title'].value;
      
        setEditable(false);
        let updateKahootQuestion = await withData(`quizQuestion/${context.selected}`,'PUT',{title});
    
        
    } 
  return (
    <>
     <form>
        <input name='title' />
     </form>
    <p>{title}</p>

    </>
 )

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem exactly and how to help you.

Comment: Is it that you're having issues with communicating to other components when `let updateKahootQuestion = await withData(...)` finishes?
If so that can be done via either internal states, or a callback that can be set, or even using React Redux.

Comment: I'm trying to allow the user to send data to the database and show the updated results immediately. Right now, I have to refresh my page to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your intention is to do this strictly through the context, but we will need more of it there to know what properties and functions are exposed from it.

Regardless, to trigger a re-render on your `MainContent` component you could also simply add in a local `useState` and update as needed. It should look something like this:

```js
export default function MainContent() {
  let context = useContext(Context);

   // Instead of just declaring a title variable, declare a title state using that same information.
   const [title, setTitle] = useState(context.data[0].title)

     async function submitTitle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let form = e.currentTarget;
        let title = form['title'].value;
      
        setEditable(false);
        let updateKahootQuestion = await withData(`quizQuestion/${context.selected}`,'PUT',{title});
    
     // Not sure what your updateKahootQuestion will look like, so for the sake of this example, will just use title.
     setTitle(title) // will trigger a re-render
        
    } 
  return (
    <>
     <form>
        <input name='title' />
     </form>
    <p>{title}</p>

    </>
 )

}
```